# displaying entire value on the y-axis in highcharts when the range between the intervals are high

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

If the data is small the y-axis looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukWwk.png)

But if the data range is high then it will be like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVQp6.png)

How can i remove the dots and show the entire value in the 2 image like it is displaying in the 1st image

Comment: This doesn't look like a default behavior of Highcharts - please post chart's configuration or even better - live example e.g. in JSFiddle.

Comment: This has been resolved.Thanks

Comment: Fell free to post solution as an answer and later you can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
formatter: function() {
                        var value = this.value.toFixed( 0 );
                        if ( value > 999999999 ) {
                            return parseInt( value / 1000000000 ) + 'B';
                        } else if ( value > 999999 ) {
                            return parseInt( value / 1000000 ) + 'M';
                        } else if ( value > 9999 ) {
                            return parseInt( value / 1000 ) + 'K';
                        } else {
                            return parseInt( value );
                        }
                    }
```